# two font types in one button style in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I got question: suppose i'm writing a java script calculator. I want for each button to have two information inside it: one is description eg '`add`' and other is in that case '`plus sign`'. I want that description has to have size `12px` however i want '`plus sign`' to have size `40px`. To sum up: two font sizes in one button. Is it possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```css
button {
    font-size: 12px;
}
button > span {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<button>Add<span>+</span></button>
```

Or with some CSS magic:

```css
button {
    font-size: 12px;
}
button:after {
    content: "++";
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<button>Add</button>
```

Feel free to modify to your exact needs.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to be an `<input type="button">` I'd use something like:

```
<button onclick="" class="button-style">
    <span class="font-style-1">add</span>
    <span class="font-style-2">+</span>
</button>
```

Then defining a button-like style for the `<button>` and something like this for your spans:

```
.font-style-1 {
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.font-style-2 {
    font-size: 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Watch it live:
http://codepen.io/PhilipFeldmann/pen/qbroJP

Comment: OP also has the option of using the `<button>` tag, i.e. `<button type="button">Add<span class="plus-sign">+</span></button>`.

Comment: Using an `<a>` tag was also an option. I suggested `<button>` because you mentioned `<input type="button">`.

Comment: I mentioned <a> earlier but in this case he had to define an extra button style (else it'll look like a normal link), which he gets for free when using <button>. The reason I did not mention <button> at first was because I thought that  <button> was not interpreted correctly by some really old browsers, but I looked it up after your comment and it seems to be fine. Thanks for the addition!

Answer (score 1):

You can nest more than 1 `<span>` inside a `<button>` element and style accordingly:

```
<button>
  <span id="a">small</span>
  <span id="b">big</span>
</button>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kweqyxok/)